# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal error in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, string-literals

while passing string parameters from java to javascript function it breaks if parameters contains space in it.

```
String str = "This is test";
sb.append("<a href=javascript:testFunction(\""+str+"\";>test</a>");
```

then while clicking on this hyper link it gives below error as:
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when I passed str as a parameter to javascript function, it gives error when I clicked on hyperlink because str contains space in it.

Comment: how should I solve this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `"` characters in an HTML attribute value which doesn't have delimiters and you are missing a `)`.

You could add the missing bits:

```
sb.append("<a href='javascript:testFunction(\""+str+"\");'>test</a>");
```

But you would be better off:

- Not constructing JavaScript by mashing together strings
- Not constructing HTML by mashing together strings
- Not using a link to run JavaScript

Such:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.type = "button";
button.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode('test')
);
button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    testFunction(str);
});
ab.append(button); // Assuming that whatever `ab.append` is accepts a DOM element
```

Comment: Thanks. sb.append("<a href='javascript:testFunction(\""+str+"\");'>test</a>"); worked

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues as I see it:

1 - Your `href`'s value isn't wrapped in quotes.

2 - Your function isn't terminated with `)`.

```
String strTest = "This is test";
String str = String.Format("<a href=\"javascript:testFunction('{0}');\">test</a>", strTest);
sb.append(str);
```

Comment: The generated string does get quotes. That's what all the escaped 
" characters are for.

Comment: @Quentin Correct, didn't notice. Thanks